# Tracing by Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, trace, qemu

I have two questions:

*** First question:

In this page of Android developers website:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

It is said that there's a `-trace` option for the emulator. However, when I run the following command:

```
me@my_computer:~$ $SDK_ROOT/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_19_ARM -trace $OUTPUT_FILE
```

I get this error:

```
unknown option: -trace
please use -help for a list of valid options
```

Also, when I run this command:

```
me@my_computer:~$ $SDK_ROOT/tools/emulator -help | grep trace
```

the result is empty.

Is this really an inconsistency between the website manual and the command line help of the emulator?

*** Second question:

Looking for a way of tracing, I found that the `-qemu` option has something like this:

```
me@my_computer:~$ $SDK_ROOT/tools/emulator -qemu -h | grep trace
-trace [events=<file>][,file=<file>]
```

But when I add the `-qemu` option:

```
me@my_computer:~$ $SDK_ROOT/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_19_ARM -qemu -trace file=$OUTPUT_FILE
```

what I get is:

```
$SDK_ROOT/tools/emulator64-arm: invalid option -- '-trace'
```

At the QEMU documention web page (http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#index-_002dtrace), it is said that:

> -trace [events=*file*][,file=*file*]
>
> ...
>
> file=*file*
>
> Log output traces to file. This option is only available if QEMU has
>   been compiled with the simple tracing backend.

Is this the reason that `-qemu -trace` doesn't work in Android emulator?

I'd appreciate it if someone helps me on this issue.

Any other suggestions for collecting traces (especially instruction traces) of a real or virtual Android device are appreciated as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, the manual page is outdated. As of now, emulator doesn't support own tracing features and it build the QEMU engine with no tracing support as well. I'll file a bug to update the manual.

Comment: That is pretty bad. There's no good native/JNI code tracing facilities on android similar to iOS Instruments.